Economics Textbooks
What are some good textbooks for learning

Microeconomic Theory
Macroeconomics
Econometrics

Are there any textbooks that are particularly popular for post-grad courses?

This question is similar to: Mathematical Micro/Macro Economics Textbook Recommendation. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also take a look at these questions seeking textbook recommendations

Microeconomic theory: Mas-Colell, Whinston and Green's Microeconomic Theory is widely used. I prefer Jehle and Reny's Advanced Microeconomic Theory, though.
Econometrics: Wooldridge's Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data. It's a bit outdated but useful. Angrist and Pischke's Mostly Harmless Econometrics is tendentious but good. Cameron and Trivedi's Microeconometrics: Methods and Applications is an excellent reference book.
Macroeconomics: Not my field, but Stokey and Lucas's Recursive Methods in Economic Dynamics is good.

Greene's Econometric Analysis is good

Hi: Peter Kennedy's " a guide to econometrics" is unique and useful as a supplement to say Greene.
